# How to set common color for navigation bars in all pages (react native) used createStackNavigator for navigation

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, navigation

How to set a common color for all navigation bar from app.js file , here we used `createStackNavigator` for navigations my app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,} from 'react-native';
  import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


import Login from './src/pages/Login';
import SignUp from './src/pages/SignUp';


export default createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
               header: null
       }
  },
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    title:"SignUp",
  },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabBarOptions` at the end of your stack navigator. See [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html), for options available for (iOS and android) in `tabBarOptions`.

And for setting common color across all screens bar, use code below.

```
export default createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
               header: null
       }
  },
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    title:"SignUp",
  },
},
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    style : {
      height: 65 ,
      backgroundColor: 'blue' , 
    }
  }
});
```